# How to make screen readers read C/F as Celsius/Fahrenheit?

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers, wai-aria

I have a simple webapp with a bunch of recipes and I'm trying to make it accessible to people who use screen readers.

Often cooking temperature is denoted simply as C (for Celsius) and F (for Fahrenheit).

Screen readers read these as letters and I thought it was a bit confusing, as we are talking about temperatures.

My goal is to maintain a sentence like this:

`<p> Turn the oven on to 350 F </p>` .

Unfortunately, screen readers read it as:

`"Turn the oven on to three hundred and fifty f"` .

I would like screen readers to pronounce it like so:

`"Turn the oven on to 350 degrees Fahrenheit"`

Is it possible to somehow specifically indicate to screen readers how to read specific letters or words? Is it achieveable using ARIA notation or should I just have a hack where I have an invisible sentence:

`<p> Turn the oven on to 350 degrees Fahrenheit </p>`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It should be denoted **`°C`** (and `°F` until USA joins other countries of this planet ^^). Only Kelvin degrees are written without a °
It should help screen readers to understand that it's a unit, though I didn't test those. Otherwise @boby212 solution with abbr element is a WCAG 2.0 Technique: [Providing definitions for abbreviations by using the abbr and acronym elements](http://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/WCAG20/WD-WCAG20-TECHS/H28.html)

Comment: Upvoting, that's just what I was going to say. More than that, in JAWS default dictionary there is an entry for degrees Fahrenheit, with a ° sign.

Comment: Sorry to revive, but using Unicode’s native ℃ and ℉ would be even more accessible. Those symbols are specifically named “Degree Celsius” and “Degree Fahrenheit” in Unicode table. VoiceOver, for example, will recognise ° as “degrees”, but won’t understand C after that; with Unicode’s ℃, it has no choice but to read it properly.

Comment: @KlimLee Yep, Unicode solution would be better: please post your comment as an answer, with IE/JAWS, Fx/NVDA and/or whatever/VO tests if you can test these combinations.

Comment: @FelipeAls Well, this is crazy, but I was wrong. I mostly tested HTML, not Unicode support, assuming the latter could not possibly be incorrect. Surprisingly, *none* on Windows (IE/Chrome with NVDA, Narrator and ChromeVox) read ℃ correctly. I’ll try JAWS + Firefox later, but have to admit it’s already clear.

Comment: At least I can confirm they are able to read ° properly. They don’t even try to understand that following “C” or “F” is a unit, though (which would, in fact, be correct behaviour if they expected normal Unicode symbols).

Answer (score 1):

Use abbr tag.

```
<p> Turn the oven on to 350 <abbr title="Fahrenheit">F</abbr> </p>.
```

But your screenreader should had been configured to speak abbreviation.

To set your Jaws:
 -> Utilities > setting center
  -> web /HTML/PDF > reading > expand Abbreviation.

Comment: Down voting because this does not work with Jaws 15 as a screen reader using either Internet Explorer or Firefox.

Comment: @Jared Does it work if you modify their default configuration or does it not work whatever you do? If it never does, then we have a UAAG problem but this answer is still the most future-proof and recommended one

Answer (score 1):

I am a screen reader user and as far as I know this is not possible. Even if it is possible it is not necessary. Anyone with enough knowledge to use a screen reader will also be able to tell by context why there is an F or C after a number. Just because it sounds confusing to you does not mean it is confusing to someone who has used a screen reader for a long time.

Comment: No, I used the defaults which is what you should expect people to do.

Comment: many wcag technique work only if user change his default setting.

Comment: thanks, @Jared, your point is valid regarding the fact that "if it confusing to me, it doesn't mean that it is confusing to someone else". At the same time, if it is confusing to me, it might be confusing to others as well.

Comment: +1 for implying that screen reader users are used to conventions that are different from sighted users. It's a perspective that is difficult for those of us who can see to grasp.

Answer (score 1):

Well, just going to post another approach to this and similar problems (like using single letters in table headers for a score board)
What you can do is as @boby212 said and use `<abbr title="celsius">°C</abbr>` but as pointed out just some screen readers announce abbreviations by default.

..so another method is by using ARIA and replacing the visual abbreviation like this:

```
<p>Put the oven on 250<span aria-hidden="true">C</span><span class="visually-hidden">Celsius</span>.
```

Then hide `.visually-hidden` with CSS, like this:

```
.visually-hidden{
  position: absolute;
  left: -999em;
}
```

As I said this can also be used with tables or displaying months with 3 letters, and many more use cases. Hope this helps in future situations.